# cpanel add pure-ftp users not belonging to any client

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

Basicly I would like to create a ftp user called ftpbackup on a Centos 5 server that has WHM/Cpanel.
i have root access.
do you have any ideea how ?

I tried:
1.useradd
2.Pure-pw useradd
3.editing  /etc/proftpd/passwd.vhosts (i know it says PRO ftp but this is where cpanel stores passwords for users i created from the cpanel interface)

authentification mecanism in pureftpd conf is Extauth pureauth ... if it helps you to recognize the prolem.

don't know what happens ....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: HopelessN00b, the original poster seems to be asking about an admin level question (e.g. administering a WHM server) as opposed to how to use a service provider's implementation of cPanel. Are you sure that's off topic? I think that falls under the on topic category of "tools used for administering, monitoring, or automating" servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/proftpd_passwd <cpuser> -a <ftpuser>:<password>:<uid>:<gid>:<cpuser>:/home/<cpuser>/public_html/ftp:/sbin/nologin
```

- `<cpuser>` = your cPanel username
- `<uid>` = user_id of cPanel user
- `<gid>` = group_id of cPanel user
- `<ftpuser>` = the user to be used for login
  for example if ftpuser = ftp then to login use ftp@domain.com

Answer (score 0):

You have cPanel, then why do you want to mess-up with cPanel setup. Do it in the cPanel way. ie, simply create a dummy domain in WHM and use it for sole FTP purpose or create an FTP account from inside your cPanel.

If you add/modify users manually, it is not necessary that it will be permanent or will not be overwritten by cPanel in the future.

-$